# connect two clients without server

Tags: java, sockets, server, connection, client

I know how to connect a client to a server, world-wide!

check this link if you want to have a quick code to workout:
http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

My question is "how can I connect two clients without the server?"

The server might be there to listen to clients, but once they connected, I want the server out of the deal and then clients can talk directly.

My server is in U.S., client A is in Europe and client B is in Asia. Clients are regular users and they just run the app and contact with other clients - it is a similar concept like team-viewer with the inter-continental peer-to-peer connection.

Again, please notice that I don't want to send anything to the server and I don't want it to be the dealer between clients. It will keep the server to always listen to new connections and prevents it from being busy delivering data between clients.

Please help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem will be that clients (assuming that they are any typical machine on the net) do not have well known IP addresses.

For two clients to talk, one of them will effectively have to become a server.  However, things like NAT and firewalls prevent a typical machine from just opening a listening socket that is available to any other machine on the internet.

Your problem is a little like the 'active' mode of the old FTP protocol, where the server connected back to the client.  This mode is difficult to use in the modern world because the servers idea of the IP address of the client is likely to be the IP address of the NAT gateway of the client's private network, and the clients idea of its IP address will be a private network IP address.

Comment: Yeah, I read about it, and I think it will not be possible.

However, I wonder how two clients can talk to each other in the fastest way possible? If I just use the server, then I have two options: 1: keep the connections alive which it makes me run out of available sockets, 2: sent query to the server whenever I want to do something, like comet, which in this case I have to accept lots of connections and identify the client and then update with the last status of the other client!

Both are heavy!

Comment: @Salivan If your clients are technology-savvy, you can just require them to do port forwarding.

Comment: Will I be able to perform this port forwarding in android, html5, etc? or is it something specific to java? I don;t want the clients to change their routers or change any settings on their ends to be able to connect to each other.

Comment: Well, I think I won't be able to make my clients be listeners and server must act as the message-dealer here.

Comment: If one of the clients is not behind a NAT, or if its NAT uses port forwarding, it can act as a listener for the other client to connect to. Port forwarding can be configured programmably if a NAT supports uPNP. Most P2P systems use a central server to coordinate the creation of connections between peers. Worse case, both clients are behind NATs without port forwarding, so a direct connection is not possible unless [TCP hole-punching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching), [UDP hole-punching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching#), and other techniques are utilized.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no standard protocols for a client behind a NAT to request the the NAT perform port forwarding on its behalf.  In other words, for a client that doesn't have control of its environment (a phone on WWAN or a laptop on a public WiFi) there isn't any way of opening a listening socket to allow an arbitrary machine on the Internet to connect to it.

Comment: My suggestion would be to increase the number of sockets/file handles available on the central server.   I imagine that a really big chat system (slack for instance?) might have many central servers and pass clients off between them to load balance the message routing.

Comment: Finally - you _might_ want to look into multicast routing.  I don't know, but perhaps a typical home WiFi/WAN router will pass multicast IP traffic through it if there is a device listening.   It's been a long time since I explored that stuff (the 'm-bone' was still a thing), so I don't know if this is still a technology that is supported....  Even more finally, you might consider IPv6.  A standard 3G data connection has a fully routable subdomain attached, and this might also apply to every other internet connection type too.

Answer (score -1):

I found this http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/11/windows-tcpip-server-performance.html doing some experiments.

If that is the case, then keeping the connections will not harm me for <3k active connections.

however, what I found in my local tests is that the worst part of client/server is the amount of time it needs to process the requests.

Although I am using threading, but we all know that threading is a fake thing to allow all part of the program run simultaneously. It is the bottleneck of the process and I have to optimize the algorithm for that part.

Comment: This shouldn't be in the answer section. Please update the question it self with  your observation.

Comment: ah yeah, but I am afraid it will distract people. what I noted here is the amount of connections that can be kept alive, where my main question was how can I kept the clients connected.

Comment: I think it is, eventually if you have a gate that can accept one request at a time, then threading won't help. by the way this question is 4 years old now, 3 years and 2 days to be exact. But yeah thanks for the comment and down-vote ;)